# Google can locate you with WiFi data, but how do the small companies do it?

Tags: wireless-networking, geolocation

My question is a extension to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/299789/how-could-google-latitude-find-my-exact-pc-location-with-no-gps-or-public-wifi) one. So even though I donot have GPS in my laptop, google knows my location because I am connected to a WiFi AP, or at least have them in my vicinity, to which other android phones with GPS are/were also connected.

I live in a country where street view never started. Yet google is  big company, and has the resources to collect the location of all WiFi APs in the world(probably through android phones). OK, but [this](https://preyproject.com/) anti-theft company seems to do the same! In their docs, it's clearly stated that they get the location of the laptop by detecting WiFi APs.

But how did these guys do it? Or is Google or other companies selling my location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Google, Apple, Microsoft and others made their own Wi-Fi BSSID geolocation databases, a company called [Skyhook](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/) made one that any company could pay a service/licensing fee to use. In fact, when Wi-Fi-based geolocation first appeared in iOS, Apple was using Skyhook, because Apple had not yet built their own database. I imagine there are competitors to Skyhook.

Several years ago, Skyhook had a public AJAX API that you could use in low volumes without paying a license fee. You could create a tool that would do a Wi-Fi scan, collate all the BSSIDs (wireless MAC addresses of APs), and send it to Skyhook's service, and a split-second later you'd get back geo coordinates. I haven't tried that service in years, so I don't know if it's still available.

Answer (score 1):

GPS is not the only way to locate a device. You can get rough location information of a device connecting to cell phone towers through triangulation. You can also get location information based on an IP address as the public addresses are registered with known entities (ISPs, etc.) so your location can be roughly pinpointed using multiple methods.

Also your Wireless card can tell where other Wireless Access Points are that are nearby and their signal strengths. This information can also be used to triangulate your location if you are near any public or commercial WAPs

Comment: Leave locating the laptop from IP address, coz in that case, they won't be able to pinpoint it to my hostel building in the campus. My question is how they have the resources to get the location using these non-GPS methods. They donot have access to telephone towers either.

Comment: Google, telecoms, ISPs, skyhook, access point manufacturers, etc dont have to sell your location. They only have to sell information about the access point locations. As someone else posted this data is publicly available in some cases.

Comment: Skyhook is still collecting WAPs: http://www.skyhookwireless.com/submit-access-point and Wikipedia's article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system has a section listing "Public Wi-Fi location databases"

Answer (score 0):

#### How does it (Prey) work?

> Basically you install a tiny agent on your laptop, tablet or phone,
> which silently waits for a remote signal to wake up and work its
> magic. This signal is sent from our hosted web service whenever you
> wish to gather information or trigger an action, like locking down the
> device. That’s pretty much it.

#### I’m a tech guy, just give me the details

> Ok, sure. On laptops, the agent checks in regularly by sending an HTTP
> request to see whether it should gather information, perform any
> actions or stay asleep. On mobiles, the process stays off and waits
> for a push notification in order to perform this check. The laptop
> client is written in Node.js and both the Android and iOS in their
> native tongues.

#### Can Prey trace a computer connected via Ethernet instead of Wi-Fi?

> Yes, it will, since **Prey only needs to get a list of the nearby Wi-Fi
> access points to get a location**, it doesn’t really require for the PC
> to be connected to any of those networks.

Source [Prey FAQ](https://preyproject.com/faq)

Comment: That explains how you can remotely access the device or trigger lock downs or data wipes, but it doesn't explain how they physically locate the laptop.

Comment: @HighTechGeek Answer updated to cover your point.